# Cassandra handshake and internode communication

Tags: cassandra, port, handshaking

While trying to use the cassandra 2.0.1 version, i started facing the handshaking with version problem .

There was an exception from OutboundTcpConnection.java stating that handshaking is not possible with a particular node.

I had a look at the TCP dump and cleared off the doubts that there was no problem in the network layer.

The application is not completing the handshaking process .Moreover , the port 7000 is still active.

For example, all my 8 nodes are up . But when i try a nodetool status, some nodes give a DN- down node status. Later on, after examining , the TCP backlog queue was found overflowing and the particular server has stopped listening for other servers in the cluster.

Am still not able to spot the root cause of this problem.

Note: I have tried with previous version of cassandra , 1.2.4, and it was working ok at that time. Before going to production , i thought it is better to go to 2.0.x version to avoid a migration overhead mainly. Can anyone provide an idea on this ?

Exception am getting is

NFO [HANDSHAKE-/aa.bb.cc.XX] 2013-10-03 17:36:16,948 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 385) Handshaking version with /aa.bb.cc.XX
 INFO [HANDSHAKE-/aa.bb.cc.YY] 2013-10-03 17:36:17,280 OutboundTcpConnection.java (line 396) Cannot handshake version with /aa.bb.cc.YY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6349.  You should upgrade.

Comment: Am facing a similar sort of an issue in 2.0.3 too. Can you check the post in the link above ?