# apache cassandra node not joining cluster ring

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I've a four node apache cassandra community 1.2 cluster in single datacenter with a seed.
All configurations are similar in cassandra.yaml file.
The following issues are faced, please help.

1] Though fourth node isn't listed in nodetool ring or status command, system.log displayed only this node isn't communicating via gossip protoccol with other nodes.
However both jmx & telnet port is enabled with proper listen/seed address configured.

2] Though Opscenter is able to recognize all four nodes, the agents are not getting installed from opscenter.
However same JVM version is installed as well as JAVA_HOME is also set in all four nodes.

Further observed that problematic node has Ubuntu 64-Bit & other nodes are Ubuntu 32-Bit, can it be the reason?

Comment: Is the problematic node the seed node?

Comment: No, it's not.
Seed node & other two member nodes of cluster are communicating via gossip protocol with each other as well as being listed in nodetool status/ring command.

Comment: Kindly help, I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of cassandra you are using. I had reported a similar kind of bug in cassandra 1.2.4 and it was told to move to subsequent versions.

Are you using gossiping property file snitch? If that's the case, your problem should have been solved by having updated cassandra-topology.properties files that are upto date.

If all these are fine, check your TCP level connection via netstat and TCP dump.If the connections are getting dropped at application layer, then consider a rolling restart.

You statement is actually very raw. Your server level configuration might be wrong in my assumption.

I would suggest you to check if cassandra-topology.properties and cassandra-racked.properties across all nodes are consistent.

Comment: Thanks Ananth, I'll try those options & update. In the meantime, could you please provide some details about the bug you've reported; like Bug ID, thread URL etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627252/cassandra-handshake-and-internode-commmunication/20688401?noredirect=1#20688401

Comment: After explicitly enabling port 9160 in that particular node it's connected to ring however other nodes are working with same configuration.
Now Opscenter is displaying error while installing from GUI as
"Unable to find a java executable!
Please install java or set JAVA_HOME.
Exit code: 4".
Though java is installed & JAVA_HOME is also set for all users.
:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/app/jdk1.6.0_16
Please help!

Comment: could someone please help!